# What species of ant is this, and is it a queen?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, ant

[image]

I found her underneath a big rock along with a bunch of much smaller *Lasius niger* workers, so 
I suspect it might be a queen. I know *Lasius niger* doesn't have soldiers, so what could it have been doing there if it wasn't their queen? Also, sorry for the bad picture quality, I couldn't find a better camera, and also don't have a proper magnifying glass.

Country: Belgium

Environment: forest

Location: underneath big rock

Behaviour: calm when walking in lighted up areas

Species it was found with: *Lasius niger* workers running around frantically (note: this specimen was much bigger than the workers)

Comment: [Wikihow > How to identify a queen ant](http://www.wikihow.com/Identify-a-Queen-Ant) might be a good first series of step to determine if it is queen. I suggest that you address the questions of this article into your post.

Comment: In which country and which environment (forest, prairie, ...) did you find it?

Comment: I know what a queen looks like, i've had many lasius niger and flavus colonys in the past, i've only never seached in forrests before.

Comment: You given many useful information. But you didn't mention its size, even approximate size. (From the appearance of cotton it seems to be within 5 mm to 1.5 cm but no better cue is there. Btw what do you mean by "Found with other insects: yes"? did you mean it was in a herd of similar-other ants? or you mean it was found mixed with insects of other species?

Comment: I dunno what i meant, with that, i'll remove it, but it's larger than 6mm, and smaller than 1cm, she's moving around very franticly when i try to measure her legnth.

Answer (score 1):

This ant looks very much like a *Camponotus pennsylvanicus* queen, but since it was found in a Belgian forest, I could be wrong. I am almost certain it is a *Camponotus* species though. I hope I could have been helpful to you!